# 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'WinJS' is undefined

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I have download the code from [CodePlex](http://codeshow.codeplex.com/)
Then I install the sdk's of live,telerik etc

After installation I ran the code and I'm getting the following error

```
   `0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'WinJS' is undefined`
```

The error occured in the Converters.Js file here it is

```
(function() {
   var r = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.roamingSettings.values;

    // Export shortDate
    WinJS.Namespace.define("codeSHOW.Converters", {  // Error Occured here

   });

})();
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you include base.js in your htm file before which ever file is making that call?

Comment: after checking it I will let u know.

Comment: It is included. `   <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/base.js"></script>`

Comment: The problem is that the references are incorrect.  The correct reference are there `<script type="text/javascript" src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0.RC/js/base.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0.RC/js/ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0.RC/css/ui-light.css" />`

Answer (score 4):

On your default.htm page (or other html pages with the same code) change the  WINJS References to the location of this in your app ie

References >  Windows Library for JavaScript 2.0  >  js > base.js

I had the same problem and just had to remove the .preview on the URL reference from

```
<!-- WinJS references -->
<link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0.Preview/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0.Preview/js/base.js"></script>
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0.Preview/js/ui.js"></script>
```

to

```
<!-- WinJS references -->
<link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/js/base.js"></script>
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/js/ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add to References Windows Library for Javascript