# Windows 8 App was working, now getting 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'WinJS' is undefined

Tags: javascript, windows-8, winjs

I have a Windows 8 app that I coded a while ago. I've been making the occasional update over the past year or so. I haven't really touched it in about 2 months. Now, all of a sudden, I'm getting the error "0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'WinJS' is undefined" when I attempt to debug the app. The error appears in my default.js file, line 5.

I have this app in source control and I tried comparing the default.js and default.htm file to what I have in source control (which I know works, because it's out in production): they are the same. I've tried running Visual Studio 2013 normally and as Administrator to no avail. I've double checked that I have base.js and ui.js properly defined in default.htm (per this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468492/0x800a1391-javascript-runtime-error-winjs-is-undefined)). I've also checked my WinJS 1.0 reference is correct in my project and verified that the files are where they are supposed to be in the file system. Intellisense works fine with the WinJS object at design-time. During debug, when I look at the DOM, I notice that base.js and ui.js aren't loaded, but other scripts are. This is obviously why I get the error.

Something to note: for the first time that I can remember, when I attempted to debug for the first time in a couple of months (as noted above), I was presented with a dialog asking about Script Diagnostics. I clicked and accepted the dialog. I don't remember ever being asked that before and certainly not for this project. Could this perhaps have something to do with the error?

I'm at a complete loss to figure this out. I've googled this error with no help. I've checked around SO to no avail either. Any help would be most appreciated as I do need to push out a fix soon, and without the ability to debug, I can't test my fix.

*Another note*: I don't think this should be an issue, but before this started happening, I had to replace my HDD due to bad sector errors. Everything was properly recovered and I haven't seen any other issues. This was done about a month ago in between the last time debug worked and this issue.

*Edit*: One more thing of possible interest... Not only can I not debug this app, but other Windows 8 apps will no longer run either. Apps like Bing Weather, Pinball FX2 and any other WinJS based apps all fail to load and crash during the splash screen. Non-WinJS apps seem to work fine. So, now I think this might be a WinJS specific issue. Permissions maybe? I've checked what I can to no avail.

Comment: Offhand, check the References in the VS project. There should be a reference there to Windows Library for JavaScript 1.0. This is what pulls the WinJS files into the project properly, because they're drawn from a shared source and don't exist directly in the project itself. If that reference is bad, or the files didn't get restored with your new HD, then they wouldn't get loaded. Right click a file and select Properties to see the assumed location. You might try deleting that reference and re-adding it through Add Reference > Windows > Extensions where it should be listed.

Comment: Yup, tried that. That was how I checked my reference. Verified the files are there and also verified the reference looks correct path-wise. However, I did try removing it and re-adding it (in references) and that didn't work either.

Comment: Next step would be to remove the reference and pull the libraries in directly to your project. If that doesn't work, then it's possible that some other piece of JS being loaded before the WinJS libraries are throwing an uncaught exception and thus stopping the parser in its tracks. But I assume you've stepped through the loading process line by line? Do you ever step into the WinJS code to see how it's being executed on startup?

Comment: Well, pretty sure that would work. But, the bigger question is why it isn't working in the first place when it was working fine before. As for the loading process, as I mentioned, the base.js and ui.js aren't loading even though they are the first scripts to load. All other scripts load up (e.g. jQuery), but those don't. One other thing... I even tried uninstalling and re-installing the WinJS 1.0 SDK and that didn't work either.

Comment: Does it work if you create a new project in VS with WinJS?

Comment: Tried that and no, still not working.

Comment: That suggests that there's something amiss with your VS installation, and that it has nothing to do with your app project itself. I suggest running VS setup and at least using the repair option, if not uninstalling and reinstalling altogether. Do be aware that if you're targeting Windows 8 and not 8.1, then you need to be using VS2012 and not VS2013 (though they can be installed side by side).

Comment: Normally, I would agree. However, I've tried re-installing VS 2012 and 2013 to no avail. Besides, when WinJS based apps from the store are also failing, this indicates something other than VS as the issue (see Edit in main post). I've also tried uninstalling and re-installing WinJS 1.0 and 2.0 to no avail.

Comment: In that case it seems to be a problem with Windows as a whole. I assume it works on other machines, e.g. have you tried opening your original project on another machine with VS installed? Perhaps running a repair on Windows would clear this up, because it doesn't seem like it's a dev-related issue at all now.

Comment: Yup, I agree. The project does work on other machines. And, I know it's something on my system. I've re-installed Windows on top of itself (i.e. not a refresh/reset, but just installed it again over itself) twice to no avail. I suspect a permissions issue somewhere, but if I can't fix it, next step would be a refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like I've solved my own issue. Here's what I did...

---

First, re-install WinJS manually: nope.

Then, re-install VS 2012: nope.

Re-install VS2013: nope.

So then, I tried putting ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES with Full Control on my profile folder and Program Files. This was bad, **don't do it**!

To fix, I tried installing Windows 8 on top of itself. Didn't work. A Refresh/Reset wouldn't work either as I tried those first.

After messing up permissions, I reset all permissions on those folders with icacls using pre-saved/backup ACL files I had (phew!).

I then (since it had been a while) ran Windows Update and got 38 updates. Rebooted a couple of times and then everything started working again. (When the permissions where screwed up, I could only run things As Administrator or they would not function.)

After all this, I started getting a new error when I tried to debug my app and some of the other WinJS based apps I have. In my app, the error related to the state and no longer that it couldn't find WinJS files. I just uninstalled them (including my app) and either re-installed (Store apps) or tried debugging again and everything worked.

Very messy stuff and I still don't know what initially caused all of this. Thanks Kraig for the help. But, looks like I'm back to normal now.